How can I ssh remotely into a server that is running a wireguard vpn client connection?
I've been able to SSH into a server that is connected to an OpenVPN vpn by running the following on the server and forwarding the appropriate port...
# creating virtual interface
ip addr add "$ip" dev "$devname" label "$devname":0
# create routing table
ip rule add from "$ip" table 401
# add the default route
ip route add default via "$dgateway" dev "$devname":0 table 401

This works even though the server is connected to an OpenVPN VPN connection.  This doesn't work when the server is connected to a Wireguard VPN connection.
This would be my Wireguard conf file
[Interface]
Address = $(echo "$wireguard_json" | jq -r '.peer_ip')
PrivateKey = $privKey

[Peer]
PersistentKeepalive = 25
PublicKey = $(echo "$wireguard_json" | jq -r '.server_key')
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = ${WG_SERVER_IP}:$(echo "$wireguard_json" | jq -r '.server_port')

Why doesn't this work with Wireguard but works with OpenVPN?  How can I connect to a server running a Wireguard VPN client connection?
